How solve IBM db2 error in production using node js?
I'm trying to fetch data from IBM db2 database using node js. I installed npm install ibm_db2 package. But, I got an error stating Error: Could not locate the bindings file.
So I installed db instead of db2 by running npm rebuild ibm_db. Which solved the error and working fine in locally but when I am trying to deploy it production server then got the same error in server log.
Note : Our server is local windows server

I did locally fine but not working production. So I want to solve the problem in server.

It means that the installation of node-ibm_db on the SERVER did not fully complete. Sometimes the cause is that the server-configuration (of firewalls, or vpn, or proxies etc) is blocking download of file "ntx64_odbc_cli.zip" which npm install ibm_db will try by default to download.
